# VMWare vCenter Configuration of Virtual Switches

Tags: switch, switching, vmware

I'm new to the Network Engineering community.

I'm also relatively new to the vSphere product line (and networking in general). I was hoping I would be able to interface multiple ESXi hosts on vCenter such that their VMs would be able to communicate with one another across a virtual switch. Is there any way I would be able to do this? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Many thanks,
akratix

[image: A layout of the ESXi servers and how the VMs would interact.]

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Unfortunately, as currently stated your question is too broad to be answered. Either it has too many possible answers or a good answer would be too long for this format. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vSwitch is a logical switch within a single host. It's defined individually on each host. If it isn't given a physical link, it will not have any connectivity beyond the host, even if it's defined on multiple hosts.

A vSphere Distributed Switch (vDS or dvs - depending on the age of the document) is defined by vcenter and applied across a cluster of hosts. Once the vDS is defined, adding a host to it applies all of the vDS networks to that host.

If you have a lot of hosts and/or networks, a vDS may be less work. I script all of my ESX deployments, so it's the same either way for me.

Comment: This approach would have worked; however, I abruptly ran into a licensing issue. Unfortunately, with the ESXi servers we're working with, they do not have Enterprise licensing features; therefore, they do not have the vDS capability. Can you, or anyone else, think of another approach that may work? Best wishes.

Comment: If the vswitches on each host are connected to a real network, then they will be able to talk to each other. All of this is well documented by vmware.